# The Tkinter Text Widget Insertion Cursor

Tags: python, text, popup, tkinter

Is it possible to get the x y coordinates of the insertion cursor in a Tkinter Text widget? I'm trying to make a popup menu that pops up next to the insertion cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `bbox` method can be used to get the bounding box of an index. You can use that to get the position relative to the window. You can use the `winfo` method to get the x/y of the window.

Typically popups appear next to the mouse rather than the insertion point (though typically, right-clicking first sets the insertion point and then displays a menu).

Comment: Thanks, I'm using this to make an auto-complete feature. I feel it's a little more natural to have the popup window near the insertion point for this particular case.