# The Tkinter Entry Widget Insertion Cursor

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to implement autocompletion for Entry widget (or, rather, enhance the recipies already published by others).  I want to make pop up appear next to insertion cursor.  The problem is, I cannot find how to get the x/y coordinates of insertion cursor.

There is a similar question: [The Tkinter Text Widget Insertion Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180944/the-tkinter-text-widget-insertion-cursor) -- but it gives an answer for Text widget, which does not work for Entry.

Comment: Looks like `entry.bbox('insert')` is supposed to do this, although I couldn't get it to return anything but zeros in a quick test.

Comment: Yes @jasonharper I tried that thing after I found that other question I referred to above, and for me it also always returns (0,0,0,0), no matter what I pass into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying Tk `Entry` widget has a `bbox` subcommand to get the coordinates of a specified item, as do `Text` and a few other widgets, but for some reason Tkinter fails to implement it on this particular widget.  (If you do try calling `.bbox()` on an `Entry`, you're actually executing `.grid_bbox()`, which is something quite different.)  However, you can usually work around missing Tkinter functionality by calling Tk directly:

```
entry._getints(entry.tk.call((entry, 'bbox', 'insert')))
```

(You can replace `'insert'` with various other forms of character index specification.)